# Entity Framework - How to update multiple table without view model

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

Actualy I want to update many tables as user clicked on SAVE UPDATE. So all changes user made (add/delete/update) will be handled in web api. I dont want to use view model because my superior said it kinda repeating model of what I've done in Angular. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, let's look at this from a conceptual level.

Since you have a Save button, this means you already have a form and you have Angular models which of course are JavaScript ones. There must be a submit button on that form and you have access to all the data in your angular app. Up to this point you don't need anything from the back-end.

Next, you need to submit the data to WebAPI. We're talking about a transfer from a front end app to a back end app. WebAPI has endpoints and they take models to capture the data. These models will be very close to your front end ones if not exactly the same. This doesn't mean that you shouldn't have them though.

When you build a system where you mix different stacks, then stuff like this where models exist in multiple places, in different formats, does happen.

There are ways of dealing with it, you could have a process where when you compile your MVC application, you add some steps to automatically generate the JavaScripts models for you, so it's not all manual, but at the end of the day you still need models on both sides if you want to make any reasonable sense of your code.

At the end of the day, you will need models on Angular side and you will need models on WebApi side. You'll need to keep them in sync somehow as well.

I would have a chat with the other person and explain these things.

If you don't want to end up in a position like this in the future, you could stick to the classic MVC way of doing things.

You didn't need to use Angular, for example. I am not saying this decision was wrong ( it entirely depends on how much it helps the project and there are valid reasons to throw it in the mix ), but the situation you are in now is a direct result of that. MVC has it's own way of building forms which uses back end models so it doesn't need JavaScript specific ones.

You could, of course, completely eliminate the back-end models and simply get the data from the submitted form ( WebApi can do that ) and then you could simply transfer that data to your Entity Framework DTOs, but it's too much hassle and it's easy to make mistakes so I wouldn't use it.